# Kong with Docker Compose on Windows: failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock

Tags: windows, docker, kong

I am experimenting with Kong deployed via Docker using Docker Compose and Docker Desktop for Windows.

When I start the container I seee a bunch of Lua errors, which from reading other posts around the net seem to maybe indicate some issue with the Nginx proxy that Kong uses under the hood.

Strangely enough I am still able to hit Kong, and I'm not aware of what actual issues this might be presenting at runtime, but I'm suspicious of any startup errors like this.

Does this suggest an issue that should be addressed?

Thanks

---

Errors:

```
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1119#0: *43 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1106#0: *45 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1110#0: *39 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1116#0: *42 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1102#0: *38 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
kong_1            | 2021/10/08 19:51:58 [crit] 1117#0: *50 [lua] balancers.lua:240: create_balancers(): failed loading initial list of upstreams: failed to get from node cache: could not acquire callback lock: timeout, context: ngx.timer
```

Docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

networks:
 kong-net:
  driver: bridge

services:

  #######################################
  # Postgres: The database used by Kong
  #######################################
  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "kong"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  #######################################
  # Kong database migration
  #######################################
  kong-migration:
    image: kong:2.6.0-alpine
    command: "kong migrations bootstrap"
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
    links:
      - kong-database
    depends_on:
      - kong-database

  #######################################
  # Kong: The API Gateway
  #######################################
  kong:
    image: kong:2.6.0-alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8000
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN_SSL: 0.0.0.0:8443
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001
    depends_on:
      - kong-migration
      - kong-database
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://kong:8001"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8000:8000"

  #######################################
  # Konga database prepare
  #######################################
  konga-prepare:
    image: pantsel/konga:next
    command: "-c prepare -a postgres -u postgresql://kong:kong@kong-database:5432/konga_db"
    environment:
      DB_ADAPTER: postgres
      DB_HOST: kong-database
      DB_USER: kong
      DB_PASSWORD: kong
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: on-failure
    links:
      - kong-database
    depends_on:
      - kong-database

  #######################################
  # Konga: Kong GUI
  #######################################
  konga:
    image: pantsel/konga:next
    restart: always
    networks:
        - kong-net
    environment:
      DB_ADAPTER: postgres
      DB_HOST: kong-database
      DB_USER: kong
      DB_PASSWORD: kong
      TOKEN_SECRET: km1GUr4RkcQD7DewhJPNXrCuZwcKmqjb
      DB_DATABASE: konga_db
      NODE_ENV: production
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

Comment: How'd you resolve it?

Comment: I dont believe I ever found a solution for this.

Comment: https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/5837

Comment: i get this error on windows 11 but all thing is fine on debian